# Drop down menu in mobiles

Tags: css

I have a drop down menu in my website and it's working fine in my laptop in any browser but there is a problem in mobiles and tables.

In laptop, when I hover the menu, it drop down automatic and when I remove the mouse the menu closes, and that's fine..

In mobiles and laptops, when I click on the menu, it drop down automatic and closes after 1 second, and this is the problem.
I need the menu to keep open until I close it manual by clicking anywhere else!

What can I do in my css?

Comment: nobody can help you if you don't provide your html & css

Comment: On some devices like iPhone, the drop down will stay open once you touch it and won't close up again. Basically, with the rise of mobiles, drop downs are even a worse solution than they used to be.

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries is very important for website to view in different device like mobiles and tablets, so you need to insert the media queries in your CSS,this website is fully Responsive and work properly in both devices.
http://www.techbian.com/dell-xps-12-worlds-first-2-in-1-4k-convertible-pc/
So, use the below code and modify it then insert it on your website's CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    }
```